# Exact Target API for Beginners

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, soap-api, ampscript

Here is the Info that was given to me:

Below are the details needed to set up the Exact Target API on your pages.

Attributes are as follows:

`%%Email Address%%`

`%%PubBrand%%` - Please use attached table for these values

`%%CHUSER%%`  - Please use attached table for these values

`%%CHUSEREMAIL%%`  - Please use attached table for these values

`%%Source%%` - Should be specific to your campaign

Triggered Send email:

Email Name: `Onsite Lead Gen Nurture Series Day 1 - Variable`

External id: `90939`

API user credentials:

User: `XXXXXXX`

Password: `XXXXXXX`

I was also told this is a Lock and Publish account.

Currently we use an enterprise software called ION to create our pages that contain the FORM where we collect email address. I have the ability to use JavaScript or I can code block a form directly on the page within the `<body>`. There is also a POST XML/JSON to Web Service feature that requires inbound and outbound data.

Where do I start?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some good places to start:

[ET/SFMC Web Service Guide](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/)

[Getting Started with the ExactTarget API](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/getting_started_developers_and_the_exacttarget_api/)

[How To Create a Triggered Send for a Lock and Publish Account](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/soap-api/creating-a-triggered-send-for-a-lock-and-publish-account-via-the-web-service-api.html)